# Combination - Choose from repeating (but limited) choices

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

If I have $5$ black balls, $5$ red balls, $5$ blue balls, choose $3$ out of them ($15$ balls), how many combinations are there? Balls with the same color are considered to be identical.

Comment: Are all black balls identical or distinct?

Comment: Balls with same color are identical

Comment: Mention that Explicitly, else it is considered to be distinct if not stated.

Comment: Just changed it. How can I solve this when they are considered identical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you had an unlimited amount of each colour of ball. The number of ways to choose $6$ would now be given by the formula $\binom {6+3-1}{3-1}$ (6 balls, 3 colours). To see this, imagine that you line up six balls in order of colour, blacks then reds then blues. Now you draw a line where the colours change (if there are no reds, you draw two lines next to each other; if there are no blacks you draw a line at the start). This gives an arrangement of six balls and two lines, and each arrangement corresponds to a different choice of balls, so there are $\binom 82$.

What's the difference with your question? The restriction that you only have $5$ of each colour simply means that you can't choose all six to be the same. So $3$ of the above choices are not allowed, and you get $\binom82-3$.

Comment: Thanks. What if I choose 3 out of 15? There'll be repetitions

Comment: Than just consider the balls to be infinite.There will be no change in your answer. Imagine.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I got it. It should be 5 choose 2 ?

Comment: Yes, that's right, if you only choose 3 it is $\binom 52$ and you don't have to subtract anything because you've got enough balls of each type for any possible choice.